# Cant catch user non input

Tags: c#, .net

I want to catch when a user make an invalid input and if they have no input. I can only catch the invalid input.

```cs
string filename;
            Bitmap picture;
            Console.Write("Write the file you want to edit; ")
            try
            {
                filename = Console.ReadLine();
                picture = new Bitmap(filename);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No file choosen");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not valid");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
```

Comment: This is about exception handling. And there are two articles on the mater that I like to link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: If user made no input code will not move past `Console.ReadLine`... Could you please clarify what exactly you have problem with?

Comment: I want to catch if the user has no input in console with `ArgumentNullException`. Everytime i try it it, it goes straight to `ArgumentException`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `IsNullOrEmpty()`, for example:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)
{
    // throw an error
}
// otherwise, continue
```